# Simulating mouse button click event only works at the first click

Tags: mouse

I'm using CH9329, a uart to USB keyboard/mouse simulator chip, to simulate mouse movement, with a moveable signal sender and an esp32-based signal receiver connected to it.

[sender] -> signal

signal -> [receiver->ch9329(simulate mouse)->computer]

Now I can see while I am moving my sender, the simulated cursor correctly moves and it also responses to mouse click (by clicking some desktop buttons). But, the weird thing is, if I open a whiteboard program, and want to draw a line, the cursor clicks at the first point, showing a visiable dot, but then failed to draw other points (moved correctly). However, I'm sure I am sending the right packet to indicate the mouse button is **down** (through uart tools).

In one sentence, it seems in all my "left-button-**down**" data packets, only the first packet really clicked, while other packets just let the mouse move.

How can this be possible? Any ideas? I think real mouses also report positions in the form of discrete points to the host, and the host knows how to draw a line. But my case failed.

--Edit--

I assume when using a real mouse to draw a line in a general painting program, you press the left button and then holding the button to keep it down, when you finish drawing you let the button up, right? That's what I did.

The chip protocol uses a byte to indicate the mouse state in every mouse-host communication packet. A 0x01 means the left button is down and a 0x00 means the left button is up. And when I detected a esp32 button is pressed, I begin sending 0x01 down packet, when I detected that esp32 button is up, I then changed to send 0x00 up packet.

My logs showing the button and packets I send:

```
.[0;32mI (95069) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 0
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95089) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 0
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95089) server-main: btn clicked
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95089) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95109) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95129) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95149) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95169) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95189) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95209) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95229) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95249) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95269) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95289) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 1
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95299) server-main: btn released
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95299) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 0
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95309) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 0
.[0m
.[0;32mI (95329) uart-mouse: sending to host : mouse state: 0
.[0m
```

Comment: To draw a line on most OSs and programs, the mouse must first give `left button DOWN` signal, **not** `left button CLICKED` signal. a click is a `button DOWN` immediately followed by `button UP`. Are you sending `button down` followed by multiple `mouse moved` followed by a `button UP` packets ?

Comment: [Link 1 Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171583/246799) [link 2 Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input)  [Link 3 Windows read last sentence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/mouse-clicks) "*I'm sure I am sending the right packet to indicate the mouse button is clicked *" Can you show a sample output set ?

Comment: @AJN I misused the world 'click' someway and I actually let the mouse button down by pressing a button on esp32 when begin drawing, keep the buttons down then, and finally let the mouse up by releasing the  esp32 button. So it's a 'down - holding down - up' process.

Comment: Besides I'm using macOS and drawing using an online whiteboard: https//w-xuefeng.github.io/drawing/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the reason, I made a phone call to the chip FAE, and found that I should send packets of `relative mouse location` if I want to draw a line. And I previously used `absolute mouse location` all the time. Though `absolute location` method works in general scenarios, drawing may be a case that it cannot work.